# fadein after 2s, then fadeout after 10s animation

Tags: css

I have a problem which I don't know how to solve.

I want to to get this cloud to become visible after 2s and then become invisible again after 10s. It is important that the `px` remains as I have it because the cloud should:

- travel
- become visible in the beginning of the content area
- become invisible at the end of the content area
- travel to the end of the page invisible.

CSS:

```
.cloud1 {
  margin:18px 0px 0px 0px;
  animation:mymove 31s infinite;
  animation-delay:0s;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;

  /*Safari and Chrome*/
  -webkit-animation:mymove 31s infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay:0s;
  -webkit-opacity:0 5s;
}

@keyframes mymove
{
  from {left:1050px;}
  to {left:0px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes mymove /*Safari and Chrome*/
{
  from {left:1050px;}
  to {left:0px;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with a little trick. With the animation set for 10 seconds. You can do something like this.

```
@keyframes mymove
{

    0%   {left:0px; opacity: 0;}
    20%  {left:1050px; opacity: 1; } /* This 20% will mean 2 second on a 10 seconds scale */
    100% {opacity: 0; left: 1050px; }

}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xtKuN/1)

Comment: Now i have deleted my 
@keyframes mymove
and i set in your's but it still the same. It travels from the right side to left but it is visible the whole 10s.

Comment: @Marino, Have you used my demo or?

Comment: i have klick the demo but the block in this demo is not moving nor is he fading-in or fading-out.
http://jsfiddle.net/xtKuN/

Comment: @Marino, I didn't added the codes fro webkit browsers. I thought it would be obvious to you. Anyways I have updated my answer.

Comment: I'm kindda new to this html, css,... thing and i don't know those obvious thigs.
Thank you very much it is working perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

keyframe animations with css3 are quite "exotic". Why not use jQuery and make it crossbrowser for sure?

Comment: Coz i have no idea how to use jQuery. :/ I have the .js file setup in the html but i just don't know how to use it.

Comment: There are quite a lot websites who provide basic tutorials on Javascript (and jQuery). jQuery is a library (an add-on) for Javascript. You'll need to learn it eventually. CSS3 can do some nice animations, but jQuery is still necessary for 90% of all the work.

Comment: Yes i know, i have been avoiding jQuery for to long and and i will have to learn it aventuly.
The problem is i just don't know where to strat. But i shall figure it out... soon. :)

Comment: Just start with w3schools.com ;) It ain't the most correct website but for the basic Javascript and jQuery it's pretty neat. And great to learn! ;)